# Bash command is outputting correctly, but command not found is following

Tags: bash

In my script, as part of a big expression, I have `date --date="yesterday"` and I was testing in the terminal. It works fine if its just the command on its own but when I do something like this `"$(date --date="yesterday")"`, this is the output `bash: Wed Jun  5 15:10:55 EDT 2019: command not found...`

Why is it adding command not found?

Comment: Why do you want to execute the output of `date --date="yesterday"`?

Comment: I am writing a script that checks the logs. I need yesteday's date.

Comment: when you run :

    `$(date --date="yesterday")`

This will result in "`Wed Jun  5 15:10:55 EDT 2019`" and `Wed` will be executed on the terminal. which is of course not a valid command. That is what bash is complaining here. you either need to use `echo` to print it or assign it to some variable like provided in the following answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$(foo)` means to run the command `foo`, capture its output, and insert it into the command line.

For example:

```
cat ab$(echo cd)
```

first runs `echo cd`, captures its output (`cd`), then inserts it into the command line, giving

```
cat abcd
```

then runs `cat abcd`.

When you run

```
"$(date --date="yesterday")"
```

it first executes `date --date="yesterday"`, captures its output (`Wed Jun  5 15:10:55 EDT 2019`), then inserts it back into the command line, giving

```
"Wed Jun  5 15:10:55 EDT 2019"
```

It then tries to run this as a command, which fails because `Wed Jun  5 15:10:55 EDT 2019` is not the name of an executable.

If you hadn't used quotes around `$( )`, i.e.

```
$(date --date="yesterday")
```

it would have ended up trying to run

```
Wed Jun  5 15:10:55 EDT 2019
```

and the error would have been `bash: Wed: command not found`.

If you don't want that to happen, just don't use `$( )`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: `$(..)` is called *command substitution*, where the results of the command are substituted in place of the `$(..)`. It can be used for variable assignment, e.g. `myvar=$(...)` or as explained to insert the results directly where it is called.